# jQuery attribute selector dropping trailing ] in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Hopefully you fine folks might spot my error - I'm going blind staring at it!

I'm trying to select an option with a specified id.
This works (even in IE!) in every browser except firefox.

```
$('#routeList option[id="'+selectedRouteId+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: #routeList option[id="1354"
```

As you can see, for whatever reason, the closing ] is being dropped, making it an invalid selector. Using up to date FF and **jQuery 2.1.3**

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, just use the ID. No need for the rest. `$('#'+selectedRouteId).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using brackets instead of just `#id`?

Comment: Simple `$("#" + id)`

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: $('#'+selectedRouteId) produces the same result.

Comment: What does `selectedRouteId` contain? Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Wow, I'm a goober. Thanks for inspiring me to console.log.

Comment: So the problem really was...?

Comment: I had the same line of code 50 lines above and had forgotten- this one was missing the ]

Answer (score 0):

please try to use without inner double quotes  http://jsfiddle.net/4cd0cpf6/2/

```
$('#routeList option[id=' + selectedRouteId +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: id's are unique so you should directly use id as mentioned in above comments

Comment: Descendent ID selectors have valid use cases. For example, if you only want to target `#id-one` when it's a child of `#id-two`.